# How to correctly print Indic (Telugu) text in QB64 on Windows 64-bit?

Tags: qb64, indic, glyph-substitution

QB64phoenix edition on windows 64 bit is unable to correctly print indic (telugu) . No problem printing telugu text in notepad, mspaint and Libre Office . Is text shaping handled by QB64 or Windows ? how to know ?

QB64 3.7 has _uprintstring with an example of printing russian text, in unicode utf8 . I could run the example & changed it to utf8 of Telugu giving the telugu font  The result was poor  In telugu , a consonant glyph is modified by the following vowel mark . Instead, the vowel mark glyph is printed over the unmodified consonant. How to find what is wrong, What does QB64 use to execute a print statement?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.